# Origin of statement on devas and asuras residing in same body in Kaliyuga

Tags: kali-yuga

Many years ago I read a printed compilation of verses translated into English without citation as to source (but alleged to be from śāstra), and without the Sanskrit. One of these stuck out as interesting, and I paraphrase it roughly as follows:

In Satya-yuga, devas and asuras resided in different lokas (planets); in Tretā-yuga, on different continents; in Dvāpara-yuga, in different cities; but in Kali-yuga, they reside within the same body.

While this makes logical sense as referring to daiva-sampat and āsura-sampat (as described in Chapter 16 of Śrīmad Bhagavad Gītā), I have not found any statement like this in any Purāṇa. Has anyone heard this from an authoritative source or has even a hint of a reference or attribution?

Comment: So like people in Kaliyug having kind of extreme bad and good sides to their personality maybe ? Never heard before, makes me wanna try harder to be good :D